# Angular Twitter Bootstrap - popover - how to add a line breakup

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

Please let me know how to add a line breakup in bootstrap popover.

My controller code:

```
.....
......
$scope.title = "Test Title";
$scope.content = "Line1 <br/> Line2";
........
.........
```

HTML Code:

```
<span popover-title="{{title}} popover="{{content}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter">
```

But the result comes as "Line1 
 Line2" (without break in b/n lines.

Comment: I've the same problem. Did you get the solution for this?

Comment: I am using 'tooltip-html-unsafe' for now. There you can use <b> <u> <br> etc html tags. And it looks like Bootstrap will release popup-html-unsafe sooner.

Answer (score 0):

**Take a scope variable and bind it to html as**

> `$scope.test = 'The Next, Next <br/> Generation tablet.';`
>
> `<h3 ng-bind-html-unsafe='test'></h3>`

**Here is the demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/JBalu/v36hkjhm/6/